# Mysql command in python yields: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

while trying to push a CSV file of more than 20 million rows to MySQL server, using this python code:

```
cur = connection.cursor()

query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to csv file' INTO TABLE table.name FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"

cur.execute( query )

connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enclose a string literal with a double quote in double quotes, you should either escape the double quote with a back slash:

```
query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to csv file' INTO TABLE table.name FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"
```

or enclose the string literal in triple quotes:

```
query = '''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to csv file' INTO TABLE table.name FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';'''
```